# Access user admin informations in Firebase (ReactJS / Firebase Custom Claims)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase authentication with my react app. In my component, i'm using  the following :

```
renderUser() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    console.log(user);
    return (
      <div className="nav-actions-wrapper">
        {user ? (
          // Display post link here
          <section className="nav-actions">
            <a className="btn btn-primary mr-4" href="#" onClick={this.showPostShopPopup}>
              Admin Post
            </a>
            <PostShopPopup
              user={this.props.user}
              status={this.state.postShopPopupStatus}
              hidePopup={this.hidePostShopPopup}
            />
          </section>
        ) : (
          <section>
            <a className="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#" onClick={this.showPopup}>
              Log in
            </a>
            <LoginPopup status={this.state.popupStatus} hidePopup={this.hidePopup} />     
          </section>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I've added a custom function that sets the provided email to admin: true through custom claims.  It works fine, now when I console.log(user), I see `admin: true` in my list.

Now how can I access it so I can do `{user.admin? ...: ...}`? Because right now, when I do this it throws an error saying  `Cannot read property 'admin' of null` even though in the console log it's marked as `admin: true`...

Comment: Can you share the result for this `console.log(user);` ?

Comment: It returns an object containing all infos about the user (email, emailVerified, photoURL, etc. and some other objects and arrays that aren't readable, containing weird letters and things)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom claims are not directly accessible in the [User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) object for you to use immediately.  You're going to have to call [getIdTokenResult()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtokenresult) on the User object to get a hold of the claims.  Note that it returns a promise asynchronously and yields an [IdTokenResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.IDTokenResult) object.  This object contains the [claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.IDTokenResult) you're looking for.

Comment: It just brings another issue, now my `onlick={this.showPostPopup}` brings the following error : `Cannot read property 'showPostShopPopup' of undefined`. I've tried binding it in my constructor but it still throws the error

Comment: If you have a new problem, please post it separately and explain what now isn't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

First run this snippet in your node js server.

Create a GET endpoint and just send a simple http request so this runs and creates a custom token (adds role: 'admin' in the customClaims field of the Firebase Token) for the given user id you want to make an admin.

Node.js :

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(${UID}, {admin: true}).then(claims => 
    console.log(`CUSTOM CLAIMS ADDED: ${claims}`))
```

Client (in my case is angular but the logic is the same, create a service function)

You want the idTokenResult object from the Authentication module

```
async isAdmin() {
    const { claims } = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
    return claims?.admin == true ? true || false
}
```

This returns a boolean.